# Have the static testing skus for Android In-App Purchasing changed?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

During development of an IAB system using the IabHelper I encountered something weird:

I am currently trying to create code to handle a canceled request using the static responses provided by Google. I'm launching the purchaseflow for the correct SKU, as is seen in Logcat:

```
Launching buy intent for android.test.canceled. Request code: 10001
```

According to the Google docs this should return a response code of 1 (BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED), however, I'm receiving a response code of 0 (BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) in an empty response. The rest of the log messages are these:

```
Ending async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
Purchase data: null
Data signature: null
Extras: Bundle[{RESPONSE=0}]
Expected item type: inapp
In-app billing error: BUG: either purchaseData or dataSignature is null
Extras: Bundle[{RESPONSE_CODE=0}]
Purchase failed!
```

So my question is: how can I receive a succesful response code if I'm using the android.test.canceled SKU?

**[edit]**
By the way: if I cancel the proces of android.test.purchased it will give the correct response. My guess is that Android changed something but didn't update their docs. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: I can confirm it, I'm still trying to figure out how to handle android.test.canceled and android.test.refund. They're returning 0 as responseCode and no data on getExtras().